# trying to modify the js function so that it gives the same output as it was when called the other js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jspdf, html2pdf

I am exporting the content on the webpage to the PDF file, for this i have used jsPDF API and i could able to get it work but now i want to use html2PDF as it resolves few issues which were faced when using jsPDF API.

I have written the function `$scope.exportUsingJSPDF` which is called when the button **Export Using JSPDF** is clicked. Similarly i want to implement the function `$scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF` which uses html2PDF API but could not succeed. Any inputs on how to modify  `$scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF` so that it iterates the divs and shows the div content as shown when invoked using  $scope.exportUsingJSPDF by clicking Export using JSPDF API.

Complete online example: https://plnkr.co/edit/454HUFF3rmLlkXLCQkbx?p=preview

js code:

```
    //trying to implement the below function same as $scope.exportUsingJSPDF, so
// that when user click on Export using HTML2PDF button, it exports the content to the PDF and generaes the PDF.
         $scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF = function(){
          var pdf = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4');
            var pdfName = 'test.pdf';

         pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
         pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 8.5;
         html2pdf(document.getElementByClassName("myDivClass"), pdf, function(pdf){
             pdf.save(pdfName);
         });
         }

        $scope.exportUsingJSPDF = function() {
              var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
                var pdfName = 'test.pdf';

                var options = {   pagesplit: true};

                var $divs = $('.myDivClass')                //jQuery object of all the myDivClass divs
                var numRecursionsNeeded = $divs.length -1;     //the number of times we need to call addHtml (once per div)
                var currentRecursion=0;

                //Found a trick for using addHtml more than once per pdf. Call addHtml in the callback function of addHtml recursively.
                function recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions){
                    //Once we have done all the divs save the pdf
                    if(currentRecursion==totalRecursions){
                        pdf.save(pdfName);
                    }else{
                        currentRecursion++;
                        pdf.addPage();
                        //$('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion] selects one of the divs out of the jquery collection as a html element
                        //addHtml requires an html element. Not a string like fromHtml.
                        pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function(){
                            console.log(currentRecursion);
                            recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, totalRecursions)
                        });
                    }
                }

                pdf.fromHTML($('.myDivClass')[currentRecursion], 15, 20, options, function(){
                    recursiveAddHtmlAndSave(currentRecursion, numRecursionsNeeded);
                });
            }
```

PS: I was trying to modify $scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF so that it gives the same output as generated when clicked on "Export using JSPDF" button which calls the function $scope.exportUsingJSPDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with your function using `exportUsingHTML2PDF`, the error is that you need to pass in the html to the function of `html2PDF`. Manage the page css on the basis of your need.

**EDIT: You have wrong library. Please check html2pdf.js library within the plunker**

**Working plunker:** [html2pdf](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hi0udhrM0pIXoYhOvUT8?p=preview)

```
    $scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
    html2pdf(element, {
        margin: 1,
        filename: 'myfile.pdf',
        image: {
            type: 'jpeg',
            quality: 0.98
        },
        html2canvas: {
            dpi: 192,
            letterRendering: true
        },
        jsPDF: {
            unit: 'in',
            format: 'letter',
            orientation: 'portrait'
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please find the updated demo with your code https://plnkr.co/edit/454HUFF3rmLlkXLCQkbx?p=preview . It is not showing the image and only showing first div data.  But when you click on Export Using JSPDF you can notice the generated PDF contains all div's data which i'm iterating 4 times and each div data is shown from new page.Having hard time to get the same outcome for HTML2PDF , any inputs are helpful.

Comment: As i was calling  pdf.addPage(); to add a new page for $scope.exportUsingJSPDF , i need to do the same for $scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF but could not able to get it work. Any inputs would be helpful.I want to implement the same logic in $scope.exportUsingHTML2PDF as used in $scope.exportUsingJSPDF.@Sunil Lama

Comment: @user7833845 you have wrong library check out my edited answer. Is that what you wanted? please donot forget to upvote and tick it right :p

Comment: +1 Thanks @Sunil Lama . I have few divs with id="hideThis" which i don't want to show in the generated PDF, https://plnkr.co/edit/ajGV0GqE0CYX57aTgdGK?p=preview, i have included the logic i have used for exportUsingJSPDF which restricts to export the given div's to the PDF. The other issue is in the generated PDF can i add a page break or new page when the new line start at the end of the page, right now you can notice the last line in the page is showing in two pages. How to start each div content from new page as shown for exportUsingJSPDF. For sure i will accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi @user7833845 , i have no idea on what functions are encapsulated within the library. It would be better to create a new thread for that :)

Comment: sure, accepted the answer But if u can resolve any of the issues mentioned above please modify/update the answer as i'm badly stuck at this now..@Sunil Lama

Answer (score 1):

With `JSPDF` and `HTML2PDF`, you have to get used to two fundamentally different coding styles:

- **JSPDF**: imperative (javascript statements)
- **HTML2PDF**: declarative (directives embedded in HTML)

So for page breaks:

- **JSPDF**: `pdf.addPage();`
- **HTML2PDF**: `<div class="html2pdf__page-break"></div>`

That *should* work, however `HTML2PDF` is buggy and gives a "Supplied data is not a JPEG" error when `<div class="html2pdf__page-break"></div>` is included (at least it does so for me, in Plunkr), despite being [totally what the documentation tells us to do](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf#page-breaks).

I haven't got time to debug it. You'll need to do some research. Someone will have posted a solution somewhere on the web.